# What does the 'or' statement mean in this situation in Java?

Tags: java

I had never seen this before outside an if satatement, what does the 'or' statement do here?

```
if (i >= arr[j-1])
    D[i][j] = D[i][j] || D[i-arr[j-1]][j-1];
```

Thank you.

Comment: It evaluates to a boolean value that is true if either of the two operands is true.  Can you be more specific about what your confusion is?

Comment: It does the same thing as it always does, just because you've only seen it on the context of a condition before doesn't mean it inherently has anything to do with that.

Comment: *I had never seen this before.* This line of code? Neither have we.

Comment: Just in case, this is equivalent `D[i][j] = (D[i][j] || D[i-arr[j-1]][j-1]);`

Comment: It does `or`... Actually after all code sets D[i][j] to Boolean `true` or `false` if either `D[i][j]` is `true` **OR** `D[i-arr[j-1]][j-1]` is `true` ... What is a question?

Comment: Could also use `D[i][j] |= D[i-arr[j-1]][j-1]` in this case.

Comment: @Bubletan At a tiny theoretical performance cost.

Comment: @Aaron I think that is the key point that the OP is **not** getting

Comment: @jfhgkjhgk, Read the Fine Manual. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `D` is a `boolean` matrix, than the `||` is just the regular boolean operation you have used elsewhere. That is, will result in `true` if any operand is `true`; otherwise `false`.

A quick example to get you going:

```
boolean foo = false;
boolean bar = true;
boolean a = foo || bar; // true!
```

Answer (score 1):

It helps to remember that `||` is an operator just like `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`. All of these take two values and give another value as the result. The arithmetic operators all take two numerical types and return a number. On the other hand, `||` takes two `boolean` values and returns a `boolean` value. For example

```
boolean a = b || c
```

Here `a` is false if both `b` and `c` are false. Otherwise, `a` is true.

Comment: Good answer, but I would say *binary operator* just to be precise :)

Comment: @PauloMattos Yes, that would be more specific.

Comment: @KevinO Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It's acting as a logical operation to produce a boolean (`true` or `false`) output. Assuming that the entries of the `D[i][j]` array are all boolean, then this operation takes the boolean value of `D[i][j]` and the boolean value of `D[i-arr[j-1]][j-1]`, performs a logical OR on them (i.e. returns `false` if they're both `false`, and `true` otherwise), and stores the result in `D[i][j]`

Comment: Why are you bringing binary into this? `||` is a logical operator.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe that if you were to pass a binary value instead of a boolean, that the binary value would be cast to its respective boolean by this operation.

Comment: You're mistaken. Java is a strongly typed language.

Comment: Ok then, just updated it to remove any mention of binary

Comment: @shmosel || *is* a binary operator. Binary means that it has two operands, i.e. it takes two values. A unary operator is an operator that takes one value, like ++, -- or ! (not).

Comment: @NickL That wasn't the context of my comment.

Answer (score 0):

|| is an operator in java. It will return a true or a false value.

In your case JVM will evaluate D[i][j] || D[i-arr[j-1]][j-1]

This will return a boolean (true/false value), which will then be stored inside D[i][j].

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever just typed in:

```
System.out.println(1==1);
```

if you haven't go try it :D
It prints out a boolean value (its True in this case)
The "OR" operator can be used in the same way

try putting a print statement around your example and seeing what it prints like this:

```
System.out.println(D[i][j] == D[i][j] || D[i-arr[j-1]][j-1]);
```

Comment: You're confusing `=` with `==`.